# Is vararg in kotlin useless?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am thinking about vararg (variable arguments) option in kotlin. I know it was here before kotlin in time of java, but I actually never really understand benefit of using it. If i want for example for my function myFun() to take variable number of arguments (let's say Strings), I would create myFun() in a way that it takes List of Strings. I don't see any reason for using vararg.

Is there any benefit of using vararg over List, am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

`vararg` gives you freedom to call a function with infinite number of arguments without wrapping them in a collection. Using argument of `List` type, you are in control of more than just arguments, such as mutability.

This is more opinioned answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, passing a list is one option to avoid `vararg`.

For you as the implementor of the function there is no real difference, but for the consumer it is. It's a question of function design. How do you want your clients to call your functions.

Passing a list forces the caller to create a list first and populate it with all the items before passing them to the function.

```kotlin
fun foo(list: List<Int>) { ... }
```

```kotlin
val list: List<Int> = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)
foo(list)
```

If you offer a function taking a `vararg` type the way how to call that function changes.

```kotlin
fun bar(vararg items: Int) { ... }
```

```kotlin
fun bar(1) // just passing one parameter
fun bar(1,2,3) // or maybe three, etc.
```

Both ways have their usecases.

Comment: That is the same thing. I can also pass 1 argument in List, or maybe three. And I call function practically the same way, only difference is that in first option I wrap my elements in list

"Passing a list is okay, but forces the caller to create a list first and populate it with all the items before they can call the function" -> same thing with vararg, forces to populate items in vararg. As I sayd only difference in your example is that with list you wrap items before you use them

Comment: The “only difference” you mention is precisely the reason why someone might choose to use varargs. It’s more convenient notation in certain circumstances.

Comment: Okk fair enough